# How to add nested property when creating vertex in apache-age?

Tags: postgresql, graph-databases, apache-age

I want to add nested property when creating node in apache-age like nested dictionary in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
CREATE ({key_value: {nested_key: nested_value})
```

The syntax for creating a nested map is the same as the first map.